# Parse external website table

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, web-scraping

There is a calendar on: http://www.friendsbalt.org/upper/stulife/calendar.asp in the form of a static table, I want to have a server grab and parse out the table row by row. Is this possible? How would you  do it the most efficient way possible? Code examples would be amazing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use something like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for php if you wanted it to be done by a web page.

```
require "simple_html_dom.php"; //Get this file from the link above
$html = file_get_html("http://example.com");
$data = array();
foreach($html->find("table tr") as $tr){
    $row = array();
    foreach($tr->find("td") as $td){
        /* enter code here */
        $row[] = $td->plaintext;
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Then all of the data will be in the $data variable.

```
var_dump($data); //To prove it works.
```

I would consider putting this in a 'refresh' script, and saving all the info to a database. Then you can just fetch the info from the database - which will be nearly instant.

Then, if you wanted, you could make a cron script to make this run ever hour by itself - updating the database so that the information in it stays fresh.

It really depends what you want to do with it :)

Comment: Where do I insert the HTML into the equation? $html = $dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.friendsbalt.org/upper/stulife/calendar.asp");

Comment: Hmm. Fails out with 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method simple_html_dom::file_get_html() in /home/dugley/public_html/checkin/test.php on line 4

Comment: You need to go to the Simple HTML DOM website, and download and include the file. It's an external library. I've updated the answer to show that more clearly.

Comment: I do. I have version 1.5. It's included:

include("simple_html_dom.php");

Comment: Ok I found it - that function isn't in the object, it creates the object. Sorry about that :P

Comment: Hmm. No errors this time around but it results in a completely blank page.

Comment: So you have the data - but you haven't done anything with it yet. Try putting var_dump($data); in at the end. You'll need to work out what you want to do with the data yourself.