# Datascraping With PHP

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to take advantage of DOMDocument to scrape a table from another website. I am on shared hosting.

Here is what the html looks like:

```
<tbody>

<tr class="odd">
<td class="nightclub">Elleven</td>
<td class="city">Downtown Miami</td>
</tr>

<tr class="even">
<td class="night club">Story</td>
<td class="city">South Beach</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

I tried doing:

```
<?php
$domDoc = new \DOMDocument();
$url = "http://example.com/";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$domDoc->loadHtml($html);

$domDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


$tables = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName('tbody');



$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');


 foreach ($rows as $row)
 {

  $columns = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

  print $columns->item(0)->nodeValue."/n";
  print $columns->item(1)->nodeValue."/n";
  print $columns->item(2)->nodeValue;
}
```

When I do this I get not result. I think the server is blocking my request.

Comment: If the page is not owned by you or you dont have permission to do this, "NEVER DO THIS".

Comment: But how do you assume that server is blocking your request

Comment: You should enable error reporting first, it will solve 99% of the problems even faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was used a open sources PHP packaged called Guzzle. It will even allow you to Crawl into the site you are using.

If you are on shared hosting then download Guzzle and upload it to your server.

github.com/guzzle/guzzle/releases

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
$url = 'http://example.com';

$res = $client->request('GET', $url, [
    'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
]);


$html = (string)$res->getBody();


// The @ in front of $domDoc will suppress any warnings
$domHtml = @$dom->loadHTML($html);

  //discard white space 
  $domDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

  //the table by its tag name
  $tables = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName('tbody');


  //get all rows from the table
  $rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

  // loop over the table rows
  foreach ($rows as $row)
  {
   // get each column by tag name
      $columns = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
   // echo the values  
      echo $columns->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />';
      echo $columns->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />';
      echo $columns->item(2)->nodeValue;
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `simplehtmldom` [Here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

// Find all tr 
foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) 
       echo $element->innertext . '<br>';
```

Its good library to parse HTML [Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, this is simplest solution. Use [Simple Html Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) like below way:

```
$html = file_get_html("WWW.YOURDOMAIN.COM");
$data = array();
foreach($html->find("table tr") as $tr){
    $row = array();
    foreach($tr->find("td") as $td){
        /* enter code here */
        $row[] = $td->plaintext;
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

See detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398825/parse-external-website-table).

Answer (score -1):

Your Code is perfect only remove \ 
$domDoc = new \DOMDocument();

Try

$domDoc = new DOMDocument();